# AVAudioEngine AudioFile Time Management

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I am curerntly trying to change the playback time of a song that is being played with a slider.

My problem is getting the accurate AVAudioTime to schedule the playback for based on the slider

The code (swift) looks like:

```
@IBAction func ChangeAudioTime(sender: AnyObject) {

 //get current sampleRate of song already playing


 var nodetime: AVAudioTime  = self.playerNode.lastRenderTime


 var playerTime: AVAudioTime = self.playerNode.playerTimeForNodeTime(nodetime)


 playerNode.stop()

 var time: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(Slider.value)

 var hostTime = AVAudioTime.hostTimeForSeconds(time)

 var sampleTime = AVAudioFramePosition(hosttime/UInt64(playerTime.sampleRate))

 var ExampleTime: AVAudioTime = AVAudioTime(hostTime:hostTime, sampleTime: sampleTime, atRate: playerTime.sampleRate)


 playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime:ExampleTime, completionHandler:nil)

      playerNode.play()
}
```

The max value of the slider is assigned the length of the song so that is not the issue.

The song just begins playing from the begining

The output of ExampleTime in the console is:

```
<AVAudioTime 0x1702b4160: 147.874222 s 80475 fr (/44100 Hz)>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
-(void)playAtTime:(AVAudioTime*)aTime {

startingFrame = _currentTime * self.file.processingFormat.sampleRate;
AVAudioFrameCount frameCount = (AVAudioFrameCount)(self.file.length - startingFrame);

    [_player scheduleSegment:self.file
               startingFrame:startingFrame
                  frameCount:frameCount
                      atTime:aTime
           completionHandler:^{
                NSLog(@"done playing");//actually done scheduling.
            }];
    [_player play];


}
```

scheduleFile:atTime actually plays the whole file, atTime is when it is started. I'm still figuring out how that works myself. It should be a time in the future,

In the example, _currentTime (in seconds) is the position in the song you want to start at.

Comment: yes. atTime means we are scheduling the file in that time of the future to start playing.

Comment: func createStartTime() -> AVAudioTime? {

    var time:AVAudioTime?
    if let lastPlayer = self.trackPlayerDictionary[lastPlayerKey] {

        if let sampleRate = lastPlayer.file?.processingFormat.sampleRate {

            var sampleTime = AVAudioFramePosition(shortStartDelay * sampleRate )

            time = AVAudioTime(hostTime: mach_absolute_time(), sampleTime: sampleTime, atRate: sampleRate)
        }
    }
    return time

}

Comment: This is what I use to create a time in the near future for precise scheduling. I then use this same time multiple times for a few players to sync.